# View list of updated packages after apt-upgrade on debian-based linux systems

Tags: linux, debian, package-management, packages, aptitude

I just did an update on my Debian system and it was very long.

I'd like to know now, after the upgrades have already been applied, which packages were upgraded and which were not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my Debian Squeeze I have /var/log/dpkg.log and /var/log/apt/term.log, term.log seems to be mostly the output from the install-process and dpkg.log seem to contain info about what was installed/updated/removed.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Ubuntu I have /var/log/dpkg.log. There's also /var/log/apt/history.log but as far as I know that's a quite new feature so it may not be present in your Debian system.